# ExtendScript: Align group items centered in Ilustrator

Tags: layers, illustrator-scripting, javascript

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hi, I am new to illustrator and I want to align the **textFrame** centered to the **pathItem(square)** using Extendscript as shown in picture1. I have uploaded another picture, which shows the layer and group of these objects. Actually, all these squares and textFrames in one group. let me know how can i want to align them horizontally centered according to each other.

I want to align this green square and textFrame(TEST)'s **midpoints** horizontally.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/align-text.html

Comment: i require the function name or code snippet for alignment, but thanks for the help.:)

Comment: Okay.. then check the [AI scripting guide pdf](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_Scripting_Guide_cc.pdf)

Comment: I have already go through it but nothing found related to my work. i appreciate your concern but it is not what i require. I require **Vertical center Alignment** code snippet or function in Extendscript.

Comment: This is probably better asked of Adobe if the scripting guide is insufficient.

Comment: I have done what i expected by using mathematically; yaxis - (textFrameHeight/2 - squareHeigth/2). Although, this is not general solution but right now it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by mathematically:
**y-axis - (textFrameHeigth / 2 - squareHeight / 2)**.
And **y-axis** is the position of the *square*(pathItem) and *textFrame* on the artboard which would same because of center alignment. You can get **square and textFrame height** by using **app.document.square.height or (pathItem.height)** and **app.document.textFrames[x].height**.

Thanks.